# SSRS drill through report, How do I locate the referencing report name from main report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subreport, drilldown, ssrs-2017

I have a report (developed by a previous employee), some of the columns(data) are clickable, when clicking the number(data on some of the columns) it opens another report. But when in the design mode from the first report, I could not figure out the relation to any of the clickable report name. I have checked Action property and almost with my knowledge all possible, but still unable to locate the reference/pointer to another report. Could you please let me know, how do I locate the reports? or the pointer. As I need to add a filter and columns to most of the reports. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know how do I find and fix the report as I need to add a filter and add a column to all reports.

Also, I think it's drill through the report but unable to locate the link for each column, the reports are deployed into the reporting server and accesses through the UI portal

The main report has 6 clickable columns and I see all six reports in the reporting server as well. But not sure how those are connected and how the parameters are passed, as I need to add a new parameter and new columns to all the reports except the main report

Please let me know if you need more information
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean to say there is nothing under the Action - go to report property? That's about the only way you can navigate through to a drill down report.

Comment: Thank you, harry for the response. I really appreciate it. Yes, that's 100 sure, I have been checking both (literally all) report's Action property and all says none. Are there anything in the reporting server need to check, because I have checked all the manage's properties still no luck.

Comment: I'd double check to ensure that it's the same report version.. the one on the report server and the one you are working with. If you have to, download the server version to compare. For any drill through to work, it has to have an action on the textbox item. I don't see it working any other way.

Comment: I did update one of the drill through report's parameter and added column, now the report is prompting the (drill through report ) parameter. Then I put back the copy (from original) and it's working without prompting for the parameter. I am scampling around and nothing seem figure out. I would like to send the screenshot but it's not allowed here. I went google and youtube everywhere and nothing is clicking.

Comment: Anyone have an update that how do i nail down the reference for the drill down report

Comment: I opened the main rdl file into notepad and found the tag <Drillthrough> where listed the report and parameters. But this is not showing in the SSDT, because there is no Drillthrough in the Action property, please advise

Comment: why not just modify this in XML and see if you can get it to work? I'm not sure who this would have been designed like this. Beats me for sure!

Comment: In your SSDT, when you are going to check on the Action property field, I'm assuming you are right clicking on the area where you would regularly click to get you to the drill down report. That might get you to the textbox properties, there might have been an action set up on the placeholder properties which sits inside the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue while exploring an old SSRS report and after struggling for an hour I found the previous developers have defined this action property on the field's action property inside a textbox. So instead of looking at the textbox action property, look at the field's action property and you will find the drill through report name and parameters passed.